# Kotlin Exception when mocking suspend function java.io.EOFException: Premature end of stream: expected 1 bytes

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I use **KTor** and **Kotlin Serialization** library in my android project, along with **mockk** and **junit.jupiter** for unit testing. I've encountered a problem when mocking ktor's `suspend` function `readText()`. The following unit test tests that `initErrorMessage()` function returns correct error message.

Test class:

```
class ErrorTest {

    private val errorMessage = "objectId must be provided."
    private val errorCode = 2689
    private val correctResponseJson = "{\"code\":$errorCode,\"message\":\"$errorMessage\"}"
    // ResponseException class is from ktor library
    private val exceptionMock: ResponseException = mockk(relaxed = true)

    @Test
    fun `initErrorMessage should return correct error message`() = runTest {
        coEvery { exceptionMock.response.readText() } returns correctResponseJson // <-- here is the Error occurs

        val expectedError = errorMessage
        val actualError = initErrorMessage(exceptionMock)

        assertEquals(expectedError, actualError)
    }
}
```

Method to test:

```
suspend fun initErrorMessage(cause: ResponseException): String {
    return try {
        val body = cause.response.readText()
        val jsonSerializer = JsonObject.serializer()
        val jsonObj = Json.decodeFromString(jsonSerializer, body)
        jsonObj["message"].toString()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        ""
    }
}
```

During execution of the first line in the test method I get an Error:

```
Premature end of stream: expected 1 bytes
java.io.EOFException: Premature end of stream: expected 1 bytes
    at io.ktor.utils.io.core.StringsKt.prematureEndOfStream(Strings.kt:492)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.core.internal.UnsafeKt.prepareReadHeadFallback(Unsafe.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.core.internal.UnsafeKt.prepareReadFirstHead(Unsafe.kt:61)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.CharsetJVMKt.decode(CharsetJVM.kt:556)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.EncodingKt.decode(Encoding.kt:103)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.EncodingKt.decode$default(Encoding.kt:101)
    at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatementKt.readText(HttpStatement.kt:173)
    at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatementKt.readText$default(HttpStatement.kt:168)
    at com.example.android.http.error.ErrorTest$initErrorMessage should return correct error message$1$1.invokeSuspend(ErrorTest.kt:37)
    at com.example.android.http.error.ErrorTest$initErrorMessage should return correct error message$1$1.invoke(ErrorTest.kt)
    at com.example.android.http.error.ErrorTest$initErrorMessage should return correct error message$1$1.invoke(ErrorTest.kt)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$record$block$2$1.invokeSuspend(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:28)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator$record$block$2$1.invoke(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt)
    at io.mockk.InternalPlatformDsl$runCoroutine$1.invokeSuspend(InternalPlatformDsl.kt:20)
```

How to mock this `suspend` method `readText()` without an Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the function `readText()` hasn't been mocked properly.
It is an extension function on `HttpResponse` and it has to be mocked using [`mockkStatic`](https://mockk.io/#extension-functions) function, for example like this:

```
@BeforeEach
fun setup() {
    mockkStatic(HttpResponse::readText)
}
```

`setup()` will be executed before each `@Test`, because it is marked with `@BeforeEach` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the `HttpClientCall` instead of the `ResponseException` to create an instance of the `ResponseException` without mocking (to avoid `EOFException`).

```
class ErrorTest {

    private val errorMessage = "objectId must be provided."
    private val errorCode = 2689
    private val correctResponseJson = "{\"code\":$errorCode,\"message\":\"$errorMessage\"}"

    @OptIn(InternalAPI::class)
    @Test
    fun `initErrorMessage should return correct error message`(): Unit = runBlocking {
        val responseData = HttpResponseData(
            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            requestTime = GMTDate.START,
            headers = Headers.Empty,
            version = HttpProtocolVersion.HTTP_1_1,
            "",
            coroutineContext
        )

        val call = mockk<HttpClientCall>(relaxed = true) {
            // This is how a body received under the hood
            coEvery { receive<Input>() } returns BytePacketBuilder().apply { writeText(correctResponseJson) }.build()
            // There are cyclic dependencies between HttpClientCall and HttpResponse so it's not possible to mock it in place
            every { response } returns DefaultHttpResponse(this, responseData)
        }

        val exception = ResponseException(call.response, "")
        val expectedError = errorMessage
        val actualError = initErrorMessage(exception)

        assertEquals(expectedError, actualError)
    }
}
```